# Prevent Redis/Celery scheduled tasks from being processed multiple times - Django on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, redis, celery, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for some advice. I use Celery/Redis Scheduled tasks to check changes via an API request every 10 seconds. If there is a change, a database object with the request feedback will be created and when it did some calculations a boolean named is_called will be set to True, to prevent duplicates.

This worked fine locally and for a time also on Heroku, but since an update (nothing in the task code changed) the worker seems busy and uses up to 7 ForkPoolWorkers.

For example the `ForkPoolWorker-1` will work on the same task as `ForkPoolWorker-7`, which ignores the `is_called = True` boolean and gives me duplicate calculations with 1 database object created.

What's the best way to serve a task only to 1 ForkPoolWorker at a time? I read the docs and google research, but it's not completely clear what and how to do this.

I built in Django on Heroku.

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "stockpilot.settings")

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'every-ten-seconds': {
        'task': 'get_api_task',
        'schedule': 10.0
    },
}

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Comment: Please show your Procfile.

Comment: 'release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn project.wsgi --log-file -
worker: celery -A project worker
beat: celery -A project beat -S django'

Comment: I've changed the worker to this worker: celery -A project worker --concurrency 1 -l INFO
This solves the problem of double calculations, but I don't think it's a correct fix, because we might need more forkpoolworkers...